# how do i rename file name with randomize name to determine name using powershell?

Tags: powershell

how do i  make script that rename one file mikado_price_1_2573.csv (the end of file name 1_2573 change every time) to MikadoStockFull.csv
using mask?

this code return error

```
Get-ChildItem D:\r\*.csv | Rename-Item -NewName MikadoStockFull.csv
```

Comment: The error being ... *what?*

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\r" -filter mikado_price_*.csv | Rename-Item -NewName MikadoStockFull.csv -Force
```

Comment: I see all your other answers on SO have context to them, please consider adding some for this one too :)

Comment: Honestly hard to add context when he doesn't really tell you the error. Matter of fact I think this post should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem D:\r\*.csv | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "\d_\d+\.\w+", "$(get-random)_$(get-random).csv"} -WhatIf
```

Assume all the files have the same format "mikado_price_1_2573.csv"

Once confirmed you can remove "-WhatIf"